# OpenCV Object tracking: Python & urllib to C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Issues abound: Interfacing an ip camera, namely a raspberry pi camera which streams to from the raspberry pi to my pc. Utilizing openCV; attempting to optical tracking. I have found some opensource code online which I have modified, it is in C++, while previously I was coding in Python more OSource.

So here is the block which works, notice bytes is parsed for the jpg images in python. Take note of urllib.

```
import cv2
import urllib
import numpy as np

stream=urllib.urlopen('http://<ip>:<port>/?action=stream')
bytes=''
while True:
    bytes+=stream.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
    if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes= bytes[b+2:]
        i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('Robo-View',i)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            exit(0)
```

Now for the C++ code snippet: Which i believe captures the stream from the assigned ip address. I need to find the \xff\xd8 & \xff\xd9 to identify the jpg frames.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //some boolean variables for different functionality within this
    //program
    bool trackObjects = true;
    bool useMorphOps = true;
    calibrationMode = true;
    //Matrix to store each frame of the webcam feed
    Mat cameraFeed;
    //matrix storage for HSV image
    Mat HSV;
    //matrix storage for binary threshold image
    Mat threshold;
    //x and y values for the location of the object
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    //video capture object to acquire webcam feed
    VideoCapture capture;
    //Video located at this address: 
    const std::string vidStreamAddress = "http://<ip>:<port>/?action=stream";
    //open capture object at vidstreamaddress
    capture.open(vidStreamAddress);
    //set height and width of capture frame
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_WIDTH);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_HEIGHT);
```

Help would be appreciated. Either in identifying where to place the parse snippet or if there are methods which may be available. Thanks